# Convector Framework CLI returns error when installing chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, convector

I am very new to the Hyperledger Fabric and Convector Framework and I have followed this tutorial:
https://worldsibu.github.io/convector/modules/getting_started.html

When I try to use the CLI tool and run the command (`test` is my chaincode name):
`npm run cc:start -- test 1`

It gives the following errors:

```
Installing Chaincode test version 1.0 at org1
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access 
denied: channel [] creator org [org1MSP]
...
Installing Chaincode test version 1.0 at org2
Error: error getting endorser client for install: endorser client failed to 
connect to localhost:7151: failed to create new connection: context deadline 
exceeded
```

I have not changed the configs and MSPs. 
What is going wrong and how should I start to resolve the problem? Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

@shole that documentation is now deprecated, you can use http://docs.worldsibu.com/convector for the latest versions.

About your error that usually happens when the environment gets corrupted and keeps cryptographic materials from a previous installation, try re-running `npm run env:restart` and try again.